# Store data off-blockchain using a smart contract

Tags: blockchain

I found a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7163223) which is talking about a way to store data off-chain using the blockchain. The data are sent to the blockchain with a transaction which subsequently routes it to an off-blockchain store, while retaining only a pointer to the data on the public ledger. 
In particular the paper says:

> Consider the following example: a user installs an application that uses our platform for preserving her privacy. As the user signs up for the ﬁrst time, a new shared (user, service) identity is generated and sent, along with the associated permissions, to the blockchain in a Taccess transaction. Data collected on the phone (e.g., sensor data such as location) is encrypted using a shared encryption key and sent to the blockchain in a Tdata transaction, which subsequently routes it to an off-blockchain key-value store, while retaining only a pointer to the data on the public ledger (the pointer is the SHA-256 hash of the data).

What I cannot understand is how they do it! If all the nodes on the blockchain have to execute that very transaction, it means that they all have to save those information off-blockchain causing a duplication of contents. Did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick glance at the paper in question, it makes no mention of storage replication. The use case they are describing here is to use blockchain transactions as references to physical data that is stored somewhere. The data can be accessed by anyone who has the reference to it; i.e. access to that particular blockchain system, however the data is encrypted such that only parties with the encryption key can actually decipher it. This approach allows for quick validation of data integrity while maintaining privacy.
From the perspective of the blockchain node all they see is a transaction that will be added to their local ledger, they don't actually save the data themselves.